# jQuery: Set Xml Node to DOM element

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

**Response XML**

```
<Response>
<ClientDetail>
  <FirstName>a</<FirstName>
  <LastName>a</LastName>
  <Status>Off</Status>
  <City>a</City>
  <ZipCode>12346</ZipCode>
  ............
</ClientDetail>
<ClientDetail>
  <FirstName>b</<FirstName>
  <LastName>b</LastName>
  <Status>Off</Status>
  <City>b</City>
  <ZipCode>321546</ZipCode>
  ........
</ClientDetail>
</Response>
```

**Parsing the response**

```
$($.parseXML(response)).find("ClientDetail").each(function(){
            var respRow='<tr>'+
                '<td class="ClientName">'+$(this).find('LastName').text()+', '+ $(this).find('FirstName').text()+
            '</td><td class="ClientStatus">'+$(this).find('Status').text()+
            '</td><td class="DateOfBirth">'+$(this).find('BirthDate').text()+
            '</td><td class="searchData" style="display:none;">'+this+'</td>';
            $('#clientSearchResult > tbody:last').append(respRow);
        });
```

**Setting the XML** to hidden `<td>`

```
<td class="searchData" style="display:none;">'+this+'</td>'
```

**Reading it back**

```
  var searchData = $(row).find('.searchData').data();
  alert($(searchData ).find('Status').text());
```

If this not a correct way of doing then how should I do this?

Comment: You're actually trying to output an XML node inside an element, that won't work, and you certainly won't be able to get the node back with data() ?

Comment: Then how should I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is the best way to store an xml string in page. However, to make your code work you need to transform the xml string in a "simple" string, for example changing every '<' character with the escape sequence '<':

```
$('#clientSearchResult > tbody:last').append(respRow.replace(/</g,'&lt;'));
```

When you read the string back, you can change the escape sequence '<' back to the character '<':

```
var searchData = $('#clientSearchResult > tbody:last').text().trim().replace(/&lt;/g,'<');
```

This is a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/RX6Mm/